# Are these two integrals same or different

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

$$\int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{x}^{1}e^\frac{x}{y} dy$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1}e^\frac{x}{y} dy dx$$

Comment: They are the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the order of integrations, one has
$$\int_{0}^{1}dx \int_{x}^{1}e^\frac{x}{y} dy=\int_{0}^{1}dy \int_{0}^{y}e^\frac{x}{y} dx=\int_0^1y(e-1)dy=\frac12(e-1).$$